# Display Data with Map Not Working React js

Tags: reactjs

I have data array json like this

```
    {
        "0": "data 1",
        "4": "data 2",
    }
```

Im trying display with map not working

```
{itemUrl.map((img, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{img}</div>
 ))}
```

Then i'm trying define length array but undefined

```
console.log(itemUrl.length)
```

Comment: I think it is an object, not an array, you can not map it. Try using Object.values()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map an object. Try using `Object.values()` before mapping, it returns array of values that are in the object itself.

`Object.values(itemUrl).map...` in your case.